# PHP $_GET function, error message not showing

Tags: php

I have written a script to show my news posts on my website with an extension using the `$_GET` function, in order to show a certain post listed by its ID on that page and then an else function to list all the posts on the page if the function isn't used.

My problem here is that when I view the post I want for example of ID '9' it shows, however if I go to one that doesn't exist such as '3958389583' then it just shows my styled boxes for where the news data is supposed to be printed, rather than the error message that I echoed with an if statement.

Here is this section of the code:

```
if(isset($_GET['postid'])) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET['postid']));
    $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    if (!$id) {
    echo("Error! The post you are trying to view does not exist or has been removed.");
    } else {
```

after the else statement continues the rest of the code where my news information is printed. Someone please help, I just need the error message to show. Thank you, and let me know if you need the rest of the code for any reason :)

Comment: Not an answer, but `$_GET` isn't a function, but a variable ([superglobal](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php)).

Comment: I think you're intending on checking whether the result of the query is empty.

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions for new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [**red box**](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you care to learn, [here is a good PDO tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Answer (score 2):

I think what you want to do is this:

```
if(isset($_GET['postid'])) {
    $id = mysql_real_escape_string(stripslashes($_GET['postid']));
    $result = @mysql_query("SELECT * FROM news WHERE id = '".$id."'");
    if (mysql_num_rows($result) == 0) {
    echo("Error! The post you are trying to view does not exist or has been removed.");
    } else {
```

However, you should [stop using `mysql_` functions](http://www.deprecatedphp.com/mysql).

Comment: Thank you and i'll try, I'm just pretty new to PHP and I found it easier. Also in reply to PeeHaa, sorry - Thought it was classed as a function, again i'm new to this.

Answer (score 0):

Just a thought. `id` by its name seems to be a number and you query using `id = 'id'`
Since you supressed errors - `@mysql_query` you don't see any error.
Just in case - remove supression. It may give you the answer.